# Install Apache Spot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, apache-spot

I need to install Apache Spot on Ubuntu.

http://spot.incubator.apache.org/doc/#installation

I have already did the setup of a single node cluster of Hadoop following this guide:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

And i already have installed Hive, Kafka and Spark following the guides written in Apache documentation.
The main problem is that I'm not able to configure the file '/spot-setup/spot.conf' properly because when i run the command:

```
./hdfs_setup.sh
```

the Terminal displays:

```
sudo: unknown user: hdfs
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
./hdfs_setup.sh:line 48:hdfs:command not found
./hdfs_setup.sh:line 52:hdfs:command not found
./hdfs_setup.sh: line 62:impala-shell:command not found
```

my /etc/hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 osboxes
127.0.0.2 node03
127.0.0.3 node04
127.0.0.4 node16
```

Which values should I write in the rows of spot.conf?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hadoop installation doesn't cover adding user accounts, but it is recommended. See `useradd` command https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd ... Then, `hdfs:command not found`... You need to edit your `$PATH` variable to include `$HADOOP_HOME/bin`, which again, not covered in Hadoop installation docs. Then, looks like you still need to install Impala

Answer (score 0):

Script output implies that hadoop is not properly configured in that node. Instead of installing and configuring the dependencies individually you can try [cloudera quickstart vm](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-13.html) which packages all the dependencies required for Apache Spot.